# Setup Raspberry Pi as a router

Tags: networking

I am using Raspberry Pi model B with the latest Raspbian Stretch image from "Raspbian Stretch with desktop and recommended software".

I followed [Instructables - Use Raspberry Pi 3 As Router](https://www.instructables.com/id/Use-Raspberry-Pi-3-As-Router/)
on how to setup RPi as a router. In the file `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`, I entered another name for the interface because wlan0 doesn't show up with the command `ip a`, same for the other configuration files.

Is this the right way that it would work? And which name I should specify for the interface names instead of eth0 and wlan0?

Comment: The site you linked doesn't mention "router". What OS are you using, and what did **YOU** do?

Comment: What do you want to route? **eth0** to **wlan0** or vice versa? What interface is connected to your internet router, **eth0** or **wlan0**? Please address me with @Ingo otherwise I won't see your reply.

Comment: eth1 is connected to the internet @ingo

Comment: What is **eth1**? A RasPi 3B has only one wired ethernet port **eth0**. And may you answer my other question? I cant't help you without information.